# No output generated from C function returning char*

Tags: c, string, function, char, return

I am quite new to C so my apologies if this is a straight forward problem but I cannot seem to find my error. My code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* makeString(char character,int count)
{
    int i;
    char* finalString=malloc(count+1);
    for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
        finalString[i]=character;
    }
    finalString[count]=0;
    return finalString;
}
int main()
{
    char* string=makeString('*',5);
    printf("%s\n",string);
}
```

I am trying to get an output of the finalString which would be 'character', 'count' number of times. I am not getting any errors or warnings but It is not generating any output. When debugging it runs the loop successfully but does not ever store any character into finalString. Any help appreciated.

Comment: In C we index from `0` so change `for(i=1;i<=count;i++)` to `for(i=0;i<count;i++)`. You exceeded the bounds of the memory allocation, perhaps that is why "It is not generating any output".

Comment: @weatherVane such a simple error! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many programming languages, C uses 0-based indices for arrays. The first element of the character array at `finalString` is `finalString[0]`, not `finalString[1]`.

Your `for` loop should go from `0` to `count - 1`, instead of from `1` to `count`. The line:

```
for(i = 1; i <= count; i++)
```

should instead be:

```
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

As your code is now, you have undefined behaviour, because you try to print `finalString[0]`, which is uninitialized. In this case, it seems to be `0` (`'\0'`).

---

I've ignored the fact that `makeString` is missing its closing `}`, since you say this compiles correctly, I assume that's a pasting error.

Comment: Thank you for the note on the post I have added the } , it was just a posting error. Thank you this works! really appreciate the explanation of why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C begin at 0, i.e. the 1st element is finalString[0].

Since you do not  set it, it contains garbage, and most probably a NUL which ends the string immediately.

Your loop should look like

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
...
```

and so on.